# How to create pool of clients which can handle just one task at once

Tags: java, spring-boot

My application starts couple of clients which communicate with steam. There are two types of task which I can ask for clients. One when I don't care about blocking for example ask client about your friends. But second there are tasks which I can submit just one to client and I need to wait when he finished it asynchronously. So I am not sure if there is already some design pattern but you can see  what I already tried. When I ask for second task I removed it from queue and return it here after this task is done. But I don't know if this is good sollution because I can 'lost' some clients when I do something wrong

```
@Component
public class SteamClientWrapper {

private Queue<DotaClientImpl> clients = new LinkedList<>();

private final Object clientLock = new Object();

public SteamClientWrapper() {
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // starting clients here   clients.add();     
}

public DotaClientImpl getClient() {
    return getClient(false);
}

public DotaClientImpl getClient(boolean freeLast) {
    synchronized (clients) {
        if (!clients.isEmpty()) {
            return freeLast ? clients.poll() : clients.peek();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public void postClient(DotaClientImpl client) {
    if (client == null) {
        return;
    }

    synchronized (clientLock) {
        clients.offer(client);
        clientLock.notify();
    }
}

public void doSomethingBlocking() {
    DotaClientImpl client = getClient(true);
    client.doSomething();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use Spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to do that.

An Executor is basically what you tried to do - store tasks in a queue and process the next as soon the previous has finished.
Often this is used to run tasks in parallel, but it can also reduce overhead for serial processing.

A sample doing it this way would be on 
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-and-threads-taskexecutor

To ensure only one client task runs at a time, simply set the configuration to

```
    executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
```

Comment: nope. I am storing clients in queue and removing it then they start doing some blocking task